# Selenium taking a lot of time to find element by XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to scraping name and email of agents from this [site](https://www.bhhs.com/agent-search-results). The code firstly captures link to every profile on first page and then visits each profile to get name and email. But the problem is that it is taking alot of time to get anchor tag having name of agent in it. Here's the code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

class MessageIndividual(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r";C:/SeleniumDriver", teardown=False):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.teardown = teardown
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        #options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        #options.headless = True
        super(MessageIndividual, self).__init__()
        self.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.maximize_window()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.teardown:
            self.quit()
    
    def goToSite(self):

        url = 'https://www.bhhs.com/agent-search-results'
        self.get(url)            
    
    def getDetails(self):        

        mylist = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(self, 1000).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//section[@class='cmp-agent-results-list-view']/div[@class='cmp-agent-results-list-view__content container ']/div[@class='row associate pt-3 pb-3 ']/div[@class='col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 order-lg-3 associate__btn-group']/section[2]/a[@href]")))]
        
        for i in mylist:
            
            self.execute_script("window.open('');")
            self.switch_to.window(self.window_handles[1])
            self.get(i)                        
            
            name = WebDriverWait(self,5).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//h1[@class="cmp-agent__name"]/a[1]'))
            )            
            print(name.text)

            email = WebDriverWait(self,1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'cmp-agent-details__mail')))
            print(email.text)            

            self.close()
            self.switch_to.window(self.window_handles[0])
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inst = MessageIndividual(teardown=False)
    inst.goToSite()
    inst.getDetails()
```

Is there any way I can scrape name in lesser time?

Comment: why do you need to open a new window in every iteration? you can simply iterate on the parent window and that will save a lot of time as well.

Comment: Thats because later on I will be extracting names and emails from next pages on website.

Comment: I would suggest first capture all the links from all pages and then iterate in one browser window only, that will reduce lots of execution time.

Comment: sure, will implement it this way but the real problem that is capturing name in more time still remains.

Comment: Capturing name in more time, didn’t get that.

Comment: I mean selenium is taking alot of time to find the element inside for loop (variable : name) whose xpath is '//h1[@class="cmp-agent__name"]/a[1]'

Comment: That because every iteration you are opening a new window and then switch to the new window and then page loaded it’s all accounted. That’s why I said capture all links at once and then iterate on the same window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the `xpath` to identify the anchor tag and remove the new window open in each iteration. hope this will reduce some time.

```
def getDetails(self):        

        mylist = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(self, 1000).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[.//span[normalize-space(.)='agent details']]")))]
        
        for i in mylist:
            
            #self.execute_script("window.open('');")
            #self.switch_to.window(self.window_handles[1])
            self.get(i)                        
            
            name = WebDriverWait(self,5).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//h1[@class="cmp-agent__name"]/a[1]'))
            )            
            print(name.text)

            email = WebDriverWait(self,1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'cmp-agent-details__mail')))
            print(email.text)            

            #self.close()
            #self.switch_to.window(self.window_handles[0])
```